# Can't calculate the difference between 2 days in hours

Tags: python

I need to check if some date and now arent' different more than in 18 hours:

```
dt = parser.parse("some date 123") #working well

diff = datetime.datetime.now() - dt
print "datetime.datetime.now() - dt = %s" % diff  # 31 days, 0:08:04.882498 -- correct
print "datetime.datetime.now() - dt seconds = %s" % diff.seconds # 484 -- too

(datetime.datetime.now() - dt).seconds / 3600) < 18 # returns True always
```

As you can see, even though the dates are different in 31 days, the amount of seconds if very little which doesn't allow me to calculate the amount of hours. Why is it so small? Should it be x * 60 * 60 * amount_of_days? And how can I do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seconds` is returning just the number of seconds, not the total number of seconds, for that you can use [`timedelta.total_seconds`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds).

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
from datetime import date

date0 = date(2014, 9, 07)
date1 = date(2014, 9, 05)
diff = date0 - date1
print diff.days * 24
```

Also check [How do I check the difference, in seconds, between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362491/how-do-i-check-the-difference-in-seconds-between-two-dates)

or

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date0 = datetime(2014,09,07,0,0,0)
>>> date1 = datetime(2014,09,01,23,59,59)
>>> date0-date1
datetime.timedelta(6, 1)
>>> (date0-date1).days * 24
144
```

Comment: why do you multiple diff.days by 24?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp:- I thought you wanted the differences in hours. So 1 day is equal to 24 hence multiplied by 24. Did I missed anything?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Thats what I answered. If you get the diff in days then multiply it with 24

Comment: but how about 18 hours? Are you sure this code can return the amount of hours different from x * 24, for example, 29? Should I use total_seconds in place of?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp:- You can give it a try and tell us if you face any problem :)

Comment: I just did and it didn't give me what I wanted.

Comment: The second example doesn't work, it says "SyntaxError: invalid token" for "date0  = ..."