# Get the average latency over the last X minutes efficiently

Tags: python, algorithm, redis, pip

I am interested in a package that has an interface like:

- set_latency(date, latency)
- get_average_latency(5) # returns the latency in the last 5 minutes

Is there a pip package already doing this?

Comment: Can't you just traverse the list of values backward, checking if the date is in the 5 minute range (check http://stackoverflow.com/a/17191361/2811496)?

Comment: it should have an amortized O(1) complexity for get_average_latency, otherwise it is not efficient

Comment: Do you need average value for last 5 minutes only or any period query  is possible?

Comment: I don't see how you can get below O(n). You could accumulate all the sums  in set_latency (O(N) space and time), but you would still need to find the oldest date within the X range, which is O(logn) with a balanced BST.