# timeout for 10 seconds while loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the best way to timeout while loop in python

say:

```
while not buff.endswith('/abc #'):
```

After 10 secs, if it does not match, break the  loop.

Thanks

Comment: Add more clarity to the question please. Do you want to break the `while` loop after 10 seconds?

Comment: I'm amazed no one suggested some kind of `sleep` to prevent the code from blocking other threads. Is `buf` populated asynchronously?

Answer (score 3):

You can record the time before the loop, then inside the while loop you can compare the current time, and if it's > 10 seconds, you can `break` out of the while loop.

Something like:

```
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.now()
print(start_time)

while not buff.endswith('/abc #'):
    print('waiting')
    time_delta = datetime.now() - start_time
    print(time_delta)
    if time_delta.total_seconds() >= 10:
        break
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `time_delta.total_seconds()` instead of `time_delta.seconds`? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17191361/5815327

Comment: @Deantwo - both will work the same here. The answer you are referring to is in a different context, where `seconds` is the seconds value of a time that could have many minutes and hours. 
Here, both `total_seconds` and `seconds` are for a time that starts from `0` and so return the same value (no minutes or hours are possible since we break after 10 seconds).

Comment: If you believe you can reliably say that your code will never ever be used to make a timeout that is longer than 59 seconds, sure it doesn't matter. Just seems like an issue waiting to happen.

Comment: That makes sense @Deantwo - if the person maintaining the code ever wanted to change `10` to something > 59, then this would indeed be an issue. `seconds` is valid in this context (< 60) only, whereas `total_seconds()` would be valid for any timeout value.

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is to end the loop after 10 seconds, try the below code.

```
from datetime import datetime 
t1 = datetime.now()
while (datetime.now()-t1).seconds <= 10:
  #do something
  print(datetime.now())
```

Else check for the time difference inside the loop and break it. Like,

```
t1 = datetime.now()  
while not buff.endswith('/abc #'):
  if (datetime.now()-t1).seconds > 10:
    break
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `(datetime.now()-t1).total_seconds()` instead of `.seconds`? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17191361/5815327

Answer (score 1):

You can use [interrupting cow package](https://pypi.org/project/interruptingcow/) and put you code inside a  `with` management statement.

```
import interruptingcow
TIME_WAIT=20 #time in seconds

class TimeOutError(Exception):
    """InterruptingCow exceptions cause by timeout"""
    pass

with interruptingcow.timeout(TIME_WAIT, exception=TimeOutError):
    while not buff.endswith('/abc #'):
        pass #do something or just pass
```

As long you don't use interruptingcow with another systems that implements `SIGALARM` eg. `stopit`, `python-rq`. It will work

Comment: **Doesn't work for Windows OS**. See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52779986/8965861) and [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/evzijst/interruptingcow/issues/6)