# Why is signal.SIGALRM not working in Python on windows?

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-3.x, signals

I'm trying to understand OS concepts and Python libraries.

I came across a specific example mentioned in Python documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html link which is not working for me on Windows.

```
import signal, os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Signal handler called with signal', signum)
    raise OSError("Couldn't open device!")

# Set the signal handler and a 5-second alarm
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(5)
# This open() may hang indefinitely
fd = os.open('/dev/ttyS0', os.O_RDWR)

signal.alarm(0)          # Disable the alarm
```

Is there any specific reason why singal.SIGALRM is not working on windows?

Auto complete is even showing the SIGALRM in Pycharm IDE (I'm assuming that there will be a variable or function if it shows like that).

But when I run the program, it is giving me the below error on Windows. I haven't checked this on Linux.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/preddy53/Desktop/syst.py", line 8, in <module>
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGALRM'
```

Where am I doing wrong? Is it specific to operating system only?

Comment: Because Windows doesn't have such a signal.

Comment: As it will not have `/dev/ttyS0`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Is there any specific reason why singal.SIGALRM is not working on windows?

Yes, Windows OS *doesn't implement that signal*. The [example you found](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#example) starts with:

> Here is a minimal example program. It uses the `alarm()` function to limit the time spent waiting to open a file; *[...]*

and the [`signal.alarm()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.alarm) is documented as:

> Availability: Unix.

Next, the `SIG*` section elsewhere on the module documentation page states:

> Note that not all systems define the same set of signal names; only those names defined by the system are defined by this module.

So `SIGALRM` is not available on Windows so you get an attribute error instead.

Note that Windows also does not have a `/dev` virtual filesystem, so the `os.open('/dev/ttyS0', os.O_RDWR)` call would fail too.

See [python: windows equivalent of SIGALRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420422/python-windows-equivalent-of-sigalrm) for an alternative using threads.

Comment: ok. So, is there alternative for SIGALRM which could do more or less the same thing in Windows?

Comment: @Anudeep: I already linked to a post that talks about an alternative.