# Use LLM weights from hugging face repository

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface

So I want to use the Large Language Model from huggingface, for example [falcon](https://huggingface.co/tiiuae/falcon-7b/tree/main). So I know you can use

```
from transformers import  AutoModelForCausalLM

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("tiiuae/falcon-7b",
 trust_remote_code=True)
```

to load the model, but I want to clone the repository or download the weight, so I can use the weight on other virtual enviroment to. But currently I run to this error, when I try to load the model from the cloned repostory

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained( './falcon-7b/')
```

I have this error:

```
945 has_remote_code = "auto_map" in config_dict and "AutoConfig" in config_dict["auto_map"]
    946 has_local_code = "model_type" in config_dict and config_dict["model_type"] in CONFIG_MAPPING
--> 947 trust_remote_code = resolve_trust_remote_code(
    948     trust_remote_code, pretrained_model_name_or_path, has_local_code, has_remote_code
    949 )
    951 if has_remote_code and trust_remote_code:
...
--> 535     signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _raise_timeout_error)
    536     signal.alarm(TIME_OUT_REMOTE_CODE)
    537     while trust_remote_code is None:

AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGALRM'`
```

Do I have to do anything with the weights first?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are using the signal module on Windows.
The signal module has no attribute `SIGALRM` on windows as the signal is only available on linux. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779920/why-is-signal-sigalrm-not-working-in-python-on-windows)

Comment: Thank you. So the problem has to do with windows.