# How to get the difference in seconds between two datetimes(in PDT format) using python?

Tags: python

I have `start_time='Tue Jun  6 06:01:43 PDT 2017'` and `stop_time='Tue Jun  6 06:02:04 PDT 2017'`. I need to calculate the difference between those 2 dates in seconds/minutes/hours OR hours:minutes:seconds

I have tried datetime(stop_time) - datetime(start_time) and I'm facing this error `TypeError: an integer is required`

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362491/how-do-i-check-the-difference-in-seconds-between-two-dates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check the difference, in seconds, between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362491/how-do-i-check-the-difference-in-seconds-between-two-dates)

Comment: The question in the above link and the question I have posted are different @BaileyParker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **[dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)** to convert the string datetime to datetime object

**Sample:**

```
from dateutil import parser


start_time='Tue Jun  6 06:01:43 PDT 2017' 
stop_time='Tue Jun  6 06:02:04 PDT 2017'

dt_start = parser.parse(start_time)
dt_end = parser.parse(stop_time)

print dt_end - dt_start
```

**Result:**

```
0:00:21
```

Comment: I'm getting the result like 21000000000

Comment: I'm adding that result to a dictionary like pupils_dict['tottime'] = dt_end - dt_start. I'm getting like datetime.timedelta(0, 21)

Comment: What version of python?

Comment: Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:49:48)

Comment: Ok. This should give you the difference in string pupils_dict['tottime'] = (dt_end - dt_start).__str__()

Comment: Ohhh. Then can I get only in seconds like 21?

Comment: To get only seconds use pupils_dict['tottime'] = (dt_end - dt_start).seconds