# Python3 - Pandas Calculate time difference between stored date and current date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have following code:

```
import pandas as pd

current_date = pd.Timestamp.now() #2018-08-17 16:05:53.842894
created_date = pd.to_datetime("2018-07-23 09:52:06.090000")
diffrence = (pd.Timedelta(current_date - feed_created_date).seconds)
print(diffrence)
#output is - 22427
```

The ideal output should be 2,182,487. I am not able to findout why this is giving the incorrect output or I am doing something wrong.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `.total_seconds()` instead of .`seconds` ?

Comment: @JonClements - total_seconds() worked. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check the difference, in seconds, between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362491/how-do-i-check-the-difference-in-seconds-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `seconds` is an attribute with value between `>= 0 and less than 1 day`. Use `total_seconds()` instead:

```
diffrence = (pd.Timedelta(current_date - created_date).total_seconds())
```