# calculate time in seconds between two dates

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found this function to calculate the time difference in seconds. I have a database with this time format (variable `g`). I converted them so I got both the same time formats. but I gives me this error:

```
2018,12,09,15,34,33
2018,12,09,16,42,54
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
(v-j).total_seconds()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

What is wrong with this piece of code?

```
import datetime

g = '2018-12-09 15:34:33'
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(g, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
v = d.strftime('%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S')

j =  datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S')

print v
print j

(v-j).total_seconds()
```

Comment: `strftime` builds strings. Why are you building strings when you want to subtract date objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check the difference, in seconds, between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362491/how-do-i-check-the-difference-in-seconds-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `strptime` instead of `strftime` because you need `datetime` objects and not strings in order to make a comparison between the two and get the difference in seconds. Here is a way of doing it:

```
import datetime

g = '2018-12-09 15:34:33'
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(g, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

j =  datetime.datetime.now()

print(d)
print(j)

print((d-j).total_seconds())
```

Answer (score 0):

Omit the conversion to strings with `strftime`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> 
>>> g = '2018-12-09 15:34:33'
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime(g, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> 
>>> d - now
datetime.timedelta(-1, 81839, 567339)
>>> now - d
datetime.timedelta(0, 4560, 432661)
>>> 
>>> (now - d).total_seconds()
4560.432661
```