# pandas get integer seconds when doing a time difference instead of a x days mm:ss:hh format

Tags: python, pandas

I have two date-hour column `A` and `B` of type shown below. Both colum are in a Dataframe (pandas).

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

I create

```
df['difference'] = df['A'] - df['B']
```

I get a format like

```
0 days 00:01:13
```

I would prefer to have a column which contains the seconds in integer. For instance, I need to get 73 in my above example instead of 1min13.

How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362491/how-do-i-check-the-difference-in-seconds-between-two-dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `total_seconds`

```
(df['A'] - df['B']).dt.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, time
#Specified date
date1 = datetime.strptime('2015-01-01 01:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
import datetime
old_time = date1
print(old_time)
new_time = old_time - datetime.timedelta(hours=2, minutes=10)
print(new_time)
```