# Datetime Subtraction in Python is non symmetric?

Tags: python, datetime

When subtracting dates in python I'm finding that the results are not symmetric and the magnitude of difference depends on the order of subtraction

**Code**

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
print(sys.version)

datetime_1 = datetime.fromisoformat('2020-01-19 21:00:00').astimezone(timezone.utc)
datetime_2 = datetime_1 + timedelta(hours=1)
print(datetime_1)
print(datetime_2)

print(datetime_1 - datetime_2)
print(datetime_2 - datetime_1)

print((datetime_2 - datetime_1).seconds)
print((datetime_1 - datetime_2).seconds)
```

**Output**

```
> 3.7.2 (default, Dec 29 2018, 06:19:36)  [GCC 7.3.0]
> 2020-01-20 05:00:00+00:00 
> 2020-01-20 06:00:00+00:00
> -1 day, 23:00:00
> 1:00:00
> 3600
> 82800
```

My expectation is that the difference would be 3600 seconds, ignoring the sign, regardless of the order of subtraction. Any idea why this is not the case?

Comment: by only looking at seconds you're missing days change

Answer (score 1):

Ended up getting an answer from someone else I knew. The trick is to use total_seconds()

```
print((datetime_2 - datetime_1).total_seconds())
print((datetime_1 - datetime_2).total_seconds())
```

Same person gave me a link to the same question that I missed (making this question a duplicate)

[How do I check the difference, in seconds, between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362491/how-do-i-check-the-difference-in-seconds-between-two-dates/17191361#17191361)